# Flutter screen not refreshing after updating sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful

I am new to flutter and I am  trying sqflite. When updating database the screen not refreshing. I tried setState but not working. After hot reloading in vs code, values are changing, but when  updating automatically not refreshing. Please help with best solution.

```
class _UpdateStudentsState extends State<UpdateStudents> {
  DateTime? dateTime;
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _nameUpdateController = TextEditingController(text: widget.name);
    final _addressUpdateController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.address);
    final _mobileUpdateController = TextEditingController(text: widget.phone);
    final _emailUpdateController = TextEditingController(text: widget.email);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Text('Update Student'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _nameUpdateController,
                  ),DateOfBirth(
                    onSelectedDate: (date) {
                      dateTime = date;
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                controller: _addressUpdateController,
                  ),TextFormField(
                  controller: _mobileUpdateController,
                    ),
                  ),TextFormField(
                   controller: _emailUpdateController,
                  ),SizedBox(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child:Text('Update'),
                      onPressed: () { setState(
                          () {
                            DataBaseHelper.instance.updateStudent(
                              StudentDetails(
                                name: _nameUpdateController.text,
                                dob:
                                    '${dateTime!.day}/${dateTime!.month}/${dateTime!.year}',
                                address: _addressUpdateController.text,
                                phone: _mobileUpdateController.text,
                                email: _emailUpdateController.text,
                                id: widget.id,
                              ),
                            );
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you put your screen/widget inside a FutureBuilder?

Accessing database is an asynchronous action, you need future builder to handle the data from the database

The video below may help you a bit about the FutureBuilder

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=15